# How can I make unlimited page widgets for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to give the theme user an option to add unimited sidebars for any page. eg he can add a custom sidebar for About, News, Our Company pages etc.\

How can I impelement this in theme admin?

Answer (score 0):

I've never come across a way to do this, nor have I seen any themes that have support for this. What I do instead is to define certain areas within the theme that are widgetized. Then, use the plugin called Widget Logic to allow them to specify whether a widget should appear on a certain page.

Certainly not the most elegant solution, but it's worked so far.

For what it's worth, you might also want to check out the plugin called 'Query Posts' as it works great with the aforementioned plugin.